# Adding link to IoT.SE private beta in the IoT tag on SO

Tags: discussion, tags

Stack Exchange is launching a new Internet of Things Q&A site via Area 51. I noticed the tag [iot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot) on Stack Overflow and was wondering if it would be appropriate to add an information to that tag the same way it has been done with the Raspberry Pi tag [raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi).

This is the [Area 51 site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things) that brings people to the IoT.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt edits have just been approved, and the IoT site is now mentioned in both. I linked directly to the [site](http://iot.stackexchange.com), as it has (if you didn't join yet) a sign up link leading to the Area51 page, and it is expected to go into public beta quite soon (based on the statistics).